# How do I solve this error between Firebase and Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I am creating an app in android studio, and using firebase for our data storage.  I have followed all directions for setting up firebase to run with my app as I was told from the firebase website.  A friend in my group has the same code and is able to run the application through the emulator but mine will not work.  I am receiving the error:

```
   02 - 29 15: 54: 17.084 3604 - 3604 / my_app.my_app E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: my_app.my_app, PID: 3604
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo {
    my_app / my_app.LoginActivity
   }: java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to set the Android context using Firebase.setAndroidContext() before using Firebase.
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2327)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2476)
   at android.app.ActivityThread. - wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1344)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5417)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 616)
   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to set the Android context using Firebase.setAndroidContext() before using Firebase.
   at com.firebase.client.core.Context.getPlatform(Context.java: 45)
   at com.firebase.client.core.Context.ensureLogger(Context.java: 218)
   at com.firebase.client.core.Context.initServices(Context.java: 105)
   at com.firebase.client.core.Context.freeze(Context.java: 92)
   at com.firebase.client.core.RepoManager.getLocalRepo(RepoManager.java: 55)
   at com.firebase.client.core.RepoManager.getRepo(RepoManager.java: 19)
   at com.firebase.client.Firebase. < init > (Firebase.java: 172)
   at com.firebase.client.Firebase. < init > (Firebase.java: 177)
   at com.firebase.client.Firebase. < init > (Firebase.java: 155)
   at my_app.my_app.LoginActivity. < init > (LoginActivity.java: 79)
   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java: 1067)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2317)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2476) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread. - wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1344) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5417) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 616)
```

It seems the problem is coming from this line:

```
    The line: at my_app.my_app.LoginActivity. < init > (LoginActivity.java: 79) refers to
    /**
     * References the Firebase app with our data and authentication.
     */
   Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://MY_APP.firebaseio.com/");
```

Where I have obviously replaced MY_APP with the name of my app.  I've looked at a number of resources online and can't find anything to help me solve this issue.

Comment: What about this line?                                                            `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{my_app/my_app.LoginActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to set the Android context using Firebase.setAndroidContext() before using Firebase.`

Comment: The error is very explicit: you're not calling `Firebase.setAndroidContext()` before using Firebase. Please include the minimum code that reproduces the problem you have and we can have a look.